# Does "turn in" in this context mean "return" or "give back"?

Tags: vocabulary

> Deliberately procrastinating is another characteristic passive-aggressive behavior. When confronted with tasks that they do not want to do or appointments they do not wish to keep, the passive-aggressive individual will drag their feet. If they have been asked to complete a task at work, for example, they will put it off until the very last second or even **turn it in late** in order to punish the person who assigned the task.

Does it mean "...even return it in late..."?

Comment: To turn something in [to a teacher or boss]. Generally, turn in an assignment (school). Turn in a task is not great, but they mean give the paper or document to the person who assigned the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To turn in" is just a phrase which is generally synonymous with "submit" or "hand in" and certainly is in the case you've stated above.

As @lambie mentions, it would usually be used when talking about handing in an assignment at school, collage or work.

Here is a [wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/turn_in) article on the phrase.